# Apache PDFBox - how do i set encoding to UTF-8 (java)

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using Apache PDFBox libary for my java project and I would like to encode my text to UTF-8.

The problem is that when I want to write characters like : čćžš.... I get an error.

How do i fix this?

Comment: as far as I know, the pdf standard doesn't support utf-8

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your pivotal code.

Comment: "I want to write characters" - is your question about creating a PDF? What PDFBox version are you using? What is the code that fails? What is the error you got? Did you read the FAQ?